# Pandas Return a list of Rows whose Substrings are found in another column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have the following dataset;

[image]

I would like to end up with a column like this one;

[image]

Ideally, I would like to convert the columns to the same case and split the strings by spaces and return rows that contain a substring that is found on the other column.

Comment: Please add your input data in a way that can be copied directly into a Python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check values of [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)ed first column by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with flatten splitted values of second column and get at least one `True` value  per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filter first column and if necessary create one column `Dataframe` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a':['ga lt','ka','ku','na ma',np.nan, np.nan],
                   'column_b':['se','ga','ma po','na','ka ch', 'wa wo']})


vals = [y for x in df['column_b'] for y in x.split()]
mask = df['column_a'].str.split(expand=True).isin(vals).any(axis=1)

df = df.loc[mask, 'column_a'].to_frame('column_a_in_column_b')
print (df)
  column_a_in_column_b
0                ga lt
1                   ka
3                na ma
```